# Opening a XMLRPC Port from Apache Spark Java Code

Tags: java, apache-spark, xml-rpc

My requirement is to serve a web service request using Apache Spark.

I developed a XML RPC server which will be triggered by a servlet code and it will in-turn run a spark-submit application. XML RPC will then wait for spark-submit to complete and send the result back to servlet.

My questions are:

- Can I write a XML RPC server inside my spark job, and serve all request directly from my servlet with using standalone XML RPC server?
- What is the correct method to trigger Apache spark for each web service request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating spark with servlets can be challenging due to dependency issues, but leaving that aside, you might be better suited to having a long running driver program with a shared spark context since creating a spark context can take time (and you can't share cached data between different spark contexts). The [Ooyala Spark job server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) can be useful for this, IBM also has a project intended for doing something similar called the [Spark Kernel](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel). Hope one of these projects